# Declare a string with char data type in Objective c .m file and use it in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

Objc file

```
#import "EncryptionConstants.h"

@implementation EncryptionConstants

 char encKey[] = "secretKey";
 char iv[] = "secretIV";

@end
```

after creating a bridging file, I am doing this in a swift file..

```
var enc = EncryptionConstants()
            print(enc.encKey)
```

Getting an error like:

> value of EncryptionConstants has no member encKey.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850548/where-to-declare-a-static-variable-in-objective-c You are declaring a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header file like Below :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EncryptionConstants: NSObject
@property unsigned char* encKey;
@property unsigned char* iv;

@end
```

.m file is Below :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "EncryptionConstants.h"

@implementation EncryptionConstants

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _encKey = "secretKey";
        _iv = "secretIV";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

We have to call in swift as below :

```
let enc = EncryptionConstants()
print(String(cString: enc.encKey))
print(String(cString: enc.iv))
```

Need to include

```
#import "EncryptionConstants.h"
```

in your bridging header

Comment: It just fixes the compilation error but the value is not being set properly.

warning on the line         _encKey = "secretKey";

Assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char [10]' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

Comment: We can change the char type to NSString

Comment: It is a technical requirement to have the data type as char

Comment: I have updated the answer. `print(String(cString: enc.encKey))
    print(String(cString: enc.iv))` Please check.